# Firebase authentication disappears on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, local-storage

I have a simple react app using firebase authentication. After successful Login the ***firebase:authUser*** is stored in localStorage. But on every page refresh localStorage is being cleared and the session is lost. Browsing through other pages doesn't clear localStorage though.

Here is what it looks like in code:

1. Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

2. App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './Login';
import Main from './Main';
import Info from './Info';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Main/>} />
            <Route path="/info" element={<Info/>} />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

3. Info.js → random page that I can view without authentication needed. Refreshing while on this page (http://localhost:3000/info) also clears localStorage

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Info() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    Info page
                </div>
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                            navigate('/');
                        }
                    }>
                        Go to Main
                </button>
            </div>
        );
}

export default Info;
```

Here is firebase.js I use to authenticate user

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut, setPersistence, browserLocalPersistence } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  // Here is my config
};

initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Auth
const auth = getAuth();
var email;
var password;

// Auth - set persistance
setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);

// Auth - create
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });

// Auth - Login
signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });

// Auth - signOut
signOut(auth).then(() => {
  // Sign-out successful.
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error happened.
});

export {
  auth,
  db,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut
};
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not your browser configuration? Try changing your browser

Comment: @NestorSolalinde I have tried chrome & safari. Both act the same. Also I have tried to use SessionStorage instead of local and it has the same effect → on refresh firebase:authUser just disappears

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most browsers, when you reload the page, Firebase already restores the users authentication state from local storage by default. But since this requires it to call to the server, it may take a moment before it initialized the current user and you should use a so-called auth state listener as shown in the first code sample in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

Your code only seems to handle the case where the user explicitly logs in, so it never picks up the restored user.

---

If the above works, check if you actually need the call to `setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);`. As said, on browsers this should already be the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the kind advice, but this still didn't worked out. I tried to add this piece of code to both Info page, firebase.js and index.js. Still on page reload localStorage becomes empty

Comment: UPD: tried to set some breakpoint and get that all of the functions from my firebase.js is just executed one after another. And sing out is the last function in the list. Probably that's why my session is deleted. until breakpoint on sing out function token is still there. Now I need to find out how not to execute all those functions

Comment: Yeah, if you explicitly sign the user out their persisted data will be deleted from local storage. Once you figure out how to skip that explicit sign out (hint: I'd start by simply commenting out the call, as it's a lot less common to sign out than you may think), you may still need the `onAuthStateChanged` that I explained in my answer.

Comment: Hey @kenkech. Did you make any progress here?

Comment: Hey! @frank-van-puffelen Regarding this question I have deleted all functions from firebase.js - for some reason I thought this was a function declaration rather than execution. After that my code has stoped from login user out and the problem has gone! Thank you for your kind attention!

Answer (score 0):

Some times the onAuthStateChanged method don't solve the problem. At least in my case. Doug Stevenson wrote a blog about the "Why is my currentUser == null in Firebase Auth?".([link](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0)).

First of all the current user not binary it is actually trinary:

1. unknown (still not read)
2. sing in %100
3. sing out %100

so you need to consider there cases handle individually. He has his own example implementation in the his blog post so I will my solution here.

```
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null | undefined>(undefined);
```

I defined my user with 3 possible values so I can handle each cases.
user object enitial value is null so it is the unknown case

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
  if (firebaseUser) {
    setUser(firebaseUser);
  } else {
    setUser(null);
  }
});
```

If the user is signed out %100 the the value is null.

In my auth provider I checked all there cases

```
  if (user == undefined) {
    return <h1>loading...</h1>;
  } else if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to={"/login"} />;
  }
    return <what ever you content is />;
```