# Right way to keep Firebase user data and session stored - React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have been looking on several ways to keep the user logged in my react native application. One of those are:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       if (user) {
         setIsAuthenticated(true);
       } else {
         setIsAuthenticated(false);
       
 });
```

Which isn't working for me, whenever I press `r` on the application to hot refresh, it losses the user. 
I'm currently storing the user `email`, `uid` on the local storage, and only loggin it out whenever he presses the logout button. Is this the right way to do so? I have encountered some problems, for example. I can't use `auth().currentUser` since the data is stored in async storage.
This is how i'm managing it:

```
export default function App() {
  // Autentication
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  // Dark mode
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  // Setting location
  let [locale, setLocale] = useState(Localization.locale);
  i18n.fallbacks = true;
  i18n.translations = { en, pt };
  i18n.locale = locale;

  // Settings fonts
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Roboto_400Regular,
    Roboto_500Medium,
    Roboto_700Bold,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocale('pt');

    getData('@rememberUser')
      .then((data) => data && setIsAuthenticated(true))
      .catch(() => console.log('No user on async'));

    // auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    //   if (user) {
    //     setIsAuthenticated(true);
    //   } else {
    //     setIsAuthenticated(false);
    //   }

    //   console.log(user);
    // });
  }, []);

  if (!fontsLoaded) return <></>;

  return (
    <DataProvider
      setIsAuthenticated={setIsAuthenticated}
      setDarkMode={setDarkMode}
      darkMode={darkMode}
    >
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
        {!isAuthenticated ? (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <AuthRoutes />
          </NavigationContainer>
        ) : (
          <Provider store={store}>
            <Main />
          </Provider>
        )}
        <ToastMessage />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </DataProvider>
  );
}
```

storing:

```
async function storeData(value: any) {
  try {
    await clearAll();
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@rememberUser', jsonValue);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error on async storage');
  }
}
```

Is this the right way to keep track of the user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase authentication disappears on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870932/firebase-authentication-disappears-on-page-refresh)

Comment: @NicoleLumod Nop, this is regarding reactjs